# secure service-to-service communication in an app generated using JWT authentication

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

I read the really interesting articles:

http://stytex.de/blog/2016/03/25/jhipster3-microservice-tutorial/
http://stytex.de/blog/2016/09/15/jhipster-3-dot-7-secure-service-communication/

My question is: how can I implement secure service-to-service communication in an application generated using JWT?

I suppose AuthorizedFeignClient annotation is only available for applications generated using OAuth2.

Thanks, Mic

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how strict you see "service-to-service" communication.

### Case 1: "authenticated" is enough or you want to forward the user's permissions (authorities, roles...) to the next service

Then you can use `@AuthorizedUserFeignClient` to enable token forwarding. Here the first microservice act as the user when making requests to the second microservice.

### Case 2: request microservice should have different permissions than the user

In certain situations, you want to have different access control rules, when a request is done by a microservice, not user.

This problem is not trivial and one of the core use cases for the OAuth2 way of microservice security.

Comment: I am interested to case 1 (the first microservice act as the user when making requests to the second microservice).Thanks a lot.